# Strapi change one collection and apply change to other one

Tags: strapi

Lets say i create an entry where i can select two collections like this

[image]

now , how to detec when someone changed first collection and then apply some filter to data in second collection ?

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you're still looking for the answer but your question ranked high on my search so here's an answer for future visitors.

Say you add a post entry for your Posts collection. In the ./api/post/models/post.js you can create a hook like this

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {

   lifecycles: {
       async afterCreate(result, data) {
       const id = result.streakID;
       const streak = strapi.services.streaks.findOne({ id });

       strapi.services.streaks.update({ id }, { counter: streak.counter++ });
      },
   },
};
```

[My source](https://forum.strapi.io/t/triggering-lifecycle-hook-between-non-related-content-types/2134/2)

Best regards

EDIT: the hook runs on Post creation and accesses the Streak model by way of strapi.services.streaks. To be clear.

Comment: but this is after creation how about after selecting ?

Comment: There are plenty lifecycle hooks, you can find a list here https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#lifecycle-hooks

Comment: ok but this is after call to the db, how about after user just select item in the dropdown ?

Comment: Oh, I don't believe you can do this, you'd have to change the core strapi code. If you have multiple collections, and every item can be in many collections I'd map that as a many-to-many relational field. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe you can elaborate on your mission

Comment: Do you also know how to update the same entry? After creation I want to do something with the DB row ID, but if I try to update the current entry, it will break the server without errors. I assume that it's in an infinite loop...

Comment: If you wanna update something during the creation process, I think you need the beforeCreate hook. afterCreate shouldn't modify the entry anymore. Beware though about changing IDs, Idk how they work on Strapi but there's been some questions about changing the default ID generation and the strapi team hasn't given solutions, implying that this isn't something easy to change.